# T2252MTS Monitor - Stops working after reboot

Tags: pi-2, hdmi

I have a Raspberry PI setup and want to use a T2252MTS monitor with it. When initially connecting and using the Raspberry PI Model 2B, the monitor works, I have picture.

Althogh, after restarting the Rasberry PI, the monitor suddenly stops working. I am still able to login with SSH to the Raspberry PI and the display also works on other monitors. I have tried formatting and rewriting Rasbian image to the SD card, it did not help. I tried of course also the options in config.txt: hdmi_save, hdmi_force_hotplug, config_hdmi_boost, also did not help.

Does anyone have any ideas how to troubleshoot this? Do I also maybe need to install a particular driver? I have also tried this on a second T2252MTS monitor and had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that when the Raspberry PI is unplugged while attached to the monitor, the monitor is not disconnected. I am not sure exactly what goes wrong, although the monitor also does not work when connected to other devices if first connected to the Raspberry PI, then unplug the power from the Raspberry PI.

The fix for the monitor is to unplug it, press the power to button twice to make sure all the power is drained from the monitor and then plug it back it and it will work again.